# Expand a Rubik's Cube Commutator

Tags: code-golf, string, abstract-algebra, rubiks-cube

### Background

We will be using a 3x3 cube for this challenge.

Rubik's cubers have their own notation for movements on the cube:

- Each of the 6 faces has a clockwise turn notated with a single capital letter: `UDLRFB`. There are three additional letters `MES` denoting the three center slices.
- Counterclockwise rotations have a prime symbol appended: `U => U'`. The prime symbol for this challenge will be an ASCII apostrophe.
- A move rotated twice (either CW or CCW) has a `2` appended: `U => U2`.
- A move cannot be rotated twice and prime at the same time.
- Individual moves are separated by spaces: `U F D' B2 E M' S2`
- This challenge **will not** be using lowercase letters, which signify moving two layers at the same time.

[Commutators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator), coming from group theory, is an operation of two elements \$g,h\$ such that \$\left[g,h\right]=ghg^\prime h^\prime\$, where \$g^\prime\$ is the inverse of \$g\$, e.g. `R U F' => F U' R'`

Rubik's cubers use a similar notation to describe commutators, used for swapping  two or three pieces without disturbing any others.

Some examples of commutators:

```
[F U R, D B] = (F U R) (D B) | (R' U' F') (B' D')
[F' U2 R, D B2] = (F' U2 R) (D B2) | (R' U2 F) (B2 D') // note how B2 and U2 aren't primed
```

### The Challenge

Given a Rubik's cube commutator, expand the commutator to list out all the moves performed in it.

#### Input

Input is a Rubik's cube commutator.
Each side of the commutator are guaranteed to be at least 1 move long.
Each part of the commutator can be a separate value.
Each move in each commutator part can be separate values, as long as a CCW/prime or double move is within the value of the move (e.g. `[[R2], ...]` is valid, but `[[R,2], ...]` is not).

#### Output

Output is a list of moves of the commutator. All moves must be capital letters in the set `UDLRFBMES`, with an optional prime `'` or double move `2`.

### Test Cases

```
[[F U R], [D B]] = F U R D B R' U' F' B' D'
[[F' U2 R], [D B2]] = F' U2 R D B2 R' U2 F B2 D'
[[U F' R2 F' R' F R F2 U' F R2], [F U2 F' U2 F2]] = U F' R2 F' R' F R F2 U' F R2 F U2 F' U2 F2 R2 F' U F2 R' F' R F R2 F U' F2 U2 F U2 F'
[[M2 E2 S2], [B2 D2 F2]] = M2 E2 S2 B2 D2 F2 S2 E2 M2 F2 D2 B2
[[F], [B]] = F B F' B'
[[U], [U]] = U U U' U'
```

#### Additional Rules

- [Standard loopholes are forbidden.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- [Input and output can be in any reasonable format.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: Relevant: [Reverse a Rubik's Cube Algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/130191/reverse-a-rubiks-cube-algorithm)

Comment: The 3rd test-case has `'`s near `2`s, which seem to contradict the rules.

Comment: Did you mean *3x3**x3** cube*?

Comment: @Noodle9 [To quote OP from the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges#comment76101_24267): _The common names for Rubik's cubes are by the size of a face since they're usually cubes, so we just call them "3x3" for a 3x3x3 cube, etc. Only in cuboids like the [3x3x4 cuboid](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/cube334.htm) actually have the 3rd dimension._ (Although I personally still usually call it 3x3x3 Cube tbh, despite having collected twisty puzzles in the past.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Will the wonders of Rubik's cube never cease? I stand corrected!

Comment: Why do you not want to eliminate cancelling moves??

Comment: @user21820 at this point it's to late to change the challenge, but the logic for eliminating cancelling moves could probably be moved to a separate challenge, and would make this challenge a bit more difficult. To be fair, I didn't think about moves like `U U'` while writing the challenge so I'll leave it as is for now

Comment: @pajonk edits made

Comment: Yea I know it's not reasonable to change this challenge, but I was just wondering why you didn't want cancellation since it was even in one of your examples haha..

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>85</s> 82 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 68 bytes** by replacing two `function` occurrences with `\`s.

```r
function(g,h,`[`=gsub,`!`=function(s)rev("''"["","(\\D)$"["\\1'",s]]))c(g,h,!g,!h)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFNb4MwDL3vV5hsUhIpl/k6cUGUWy9UOTWV2FChlSo2Edq/zxxnndTS9ILM8/tw7HHu8rk7D@10/B5Ubw6m2TZ5789fpsma/L/j9bi/KCGl2AphhHKu1G9UO/cuhfG7ndYty7PeZAc9d2p/Un4a/c/pOClRgYWadCC0NnDTKqH4a@iP9pMANwj9CjmwBqgNtQQroZJQSCjly703dfGJOybsoywEICcgJVK5DLCBWyN/aQzSVMgDEfg4tWK36JmIf2YKN3oC@PGkwEiWgR1hlmBg8g8z7@dfI6wQNolZw5PTY161cKWFmpA112XAF/dI5KSuXMTLLrb@2Mam1mnDKqycfwE)

Input as two vectors of strings.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
í''««˜ε¤ºK2£
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Fp19UOrD60@Pefc1kNLDu3yNjq0@P//6GglNyUdpVAjIBGkrhSrE63kAmQ6GSnFxgIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8Nr1dUPrT60@vScc1sPLTm0y9vo0OL/tTr/o6OjldyUdJRCgThIKVYnWskFyHJSio3VUQBJqYPkjFAljWCyIE1gFUFGcBaIcAOrB9Ig4VC4iBHYCDeYiQiz3eAm@oK4riAiGKLaCcR2QVXkBpFBuALEBZKxsQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
í             # Reverse each inner list of the (implicit) input-pair
 ''«          # Append a "'" to each inner-most string
    «         # Merge this modified list to the (implicit) input-list
     ˜        # Flatten it to a single list of strings
      ε       # Map over each string:
       ¤      #  Push its last character (without popping the string)
        º     #  'Double' it with a horizontal mirror
         K    #  Remove all those substrings from the string
              #  (which will only remove potential "''")
          2£  #  Only leave (up to) the first two characters of the string
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 20 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
∾⊢∾(¬∘≠↓·⍷∾⟜"'")¨∘⌽¨
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oi+4oqi4oi+KMKs4oiY4omg4oaTwrfijbfiiL7in5wiJyIpwqjiiJjijL3CqAoKSm9pbiDihpAge+KIvuKfnPCdlajiirjiiL7CtPCdlal9Cj4oKCcgJyBKb2luwqgg4oqiKSDii4ggJyAnIEpvaW4gRinCqOKfqCgiRiLigL8iVSLigL8iUiIp4oC/KCJEIuKAvyJCIikKKCJGJyLigL8iVTIi4oC/IlIiKeKAvygiRCLigL8iQjIiKQooIk0yIuKAvyJFMiLigL8iUzIiKeKAvygiQjIi4oC/IkQyIuKAvyJGMiIpCuKfqCJGIuKfqeKAv+KfqCJCIuKfqQrin6giVSLin6nigL/in6giVSLin6nin6k=)

`¬∘≠↓·⍷∾⟜"'"` is a function that inverts a single move:
`∾⟜"'"` Append a prime symbol
`⍷` Deduplicate, This removes one `'` if the move already contained one.
`¬∘≠` Complement (1-) of the length of the move. -1 for length 2 moves, 0 for length 1.
`↓` Drop this many characters (from the end because the value is negative)

```
(⍷∾⟜"'")¨ "U"‿"U'"‿"U2"
# → U' U' U2'
¬∘≠¨ "U"‿"U'"‿"U2"
# → 0 ¯1 ¯1
(¬∘≠↓·⍷∾⟜"'")¨ "U"‿"U'"‿"U2"
# → U' U U2
```

`⌽¨` Reverse each list
`( ... )¨∘` Invert each move inside of each list
`⊢∾` Prepend the input to the result of that
`∾` Flatten by one level

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 65 bytes

```ruby
->a{[a,a.map{|x|x.reverse.map{|m|(m+?').sub("''","")[0,2]}}]*" "}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOjpRJ1EvN7GguqaipkKvKLUstag4FSKQW6ORq22vrqlXXJqkoaSurqSjpKQZbaBjFFtbG6ulpKBU@7@gtKRYIS1aITpayU1JR0EpFEQEKcXqKEQruYDYTkqxsQqx/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>15</s>  14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḟ;ċ?”'ḣ2)Ṛ)⁸;Ẏ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lists (parts) of lists of characters (moves) which yields a list of lists of characters (moves).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9qZWxsef//4bifO8SLP@KAnSfhuKMyKeG5minigbg74bqO/@G7tOG4suKCrMOHS///RicgVTIgUgpEIEIy)**

#### How?

```
ḟ;ċ?”'ḣ2)Ṛ)⁸;Ẏ - Link: list of lists of moves, A
          )    - for each Part of A:
        )      -   for each Move in that part:
    ”'         -     yield a quote character
   ?           -     if...
  ċ            -     ...condition: count     (X' -> 1, X -> 0, X2 -> 0)
ḟ              -     ...then: filter discard (X' -> X)
 ;             -     ...else: concatenate    (X -> X', X2 -> X2')
      ḣ2       -     head to index 2         (X -> X, X'-> X', X2' -> X2)
         Ṛ     -   reverse (this Part)
           ⁸   - A
            ;  - concatenate (the reversed, altered Part)
             Ẏ - tighten from a list of four parts to a list of all of the resulting moves
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
s+Qm_m+-k\'*\'hI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1g7MDc@V1s3O0ZdK0Y9w/P//@hoJTclHaVQIyARpK4UqxOt5AJkOhkpxcYCAA)

```
s+Qm_m+-k\'*\'hIkdQ
                  Q   parsed input (Q is implicit)
   m                  take each sublist d:
     m           d      map each move k inside the sublist d to (d is implicit)
       -k\'               the move k without the prime symbol
      +                   and append
              hIk         1 if the move k contains only one symbol, 0 otherwise
                          (k is implicit, actually checks if taking
                           the first character is still the complete move,
                           alternatively !tk also works)
           *\'            repeats of the prime symbol
    _                   reverse the sublists
 +Q                   prepend the complete input
s                     and merge everything into a single list of moves
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι⪫⁺υＥυ⪫Ｅ⮌⪪ι ⁺⁻λ'×'№αλ ¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BCsIwEETv/Yqll24gguTakwgBBaG09gNCjTY0JCVNqn59bAKC4GUY3gyzO4zCDVboGJ@j0hLwZObgO@@UeSAh0IRlxEBBkbq4WwfYaTVIDD/R2SqDFzFjK1fpFondrJVHRaGEkhAKV@mMcG882mA8CgrTBhsdFpy2TlX@VRJmCW/m4E/mJl@J7QlJc3m1LprtRY/5ePjCGHvgFbQsawUcWuAM@uxYwaHPSVJWxN2qPw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated string of space-separated moves. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Input the list of moves.

```
⪫⁺υＥυ⪫Ｅ⮌⪪ι ⁺⁻λ'×'№αλ ¦
```

Extend the list by taking the list of moves, splitting on spaces, reversing, inverting each move, and joining with spaces, then join the extended list with spaces and output the result. Moves are inverted by removing any `'` but then adding a `'` if the move was a single letter.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org), <s>113</s> <s>107</s> 83 bytes

```python
lambda g,h:g+h+[r(r(m+"'","2'","2"),"''","")for m in g[::-1]+h[::-1]]
r=str.replace
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZCxbtswEIaRVXMf4MCFVEwLCKfCgBHUcLVlsaGlEgclpiQWsiRQTNEgyJN0ydI-QN-meZoej7aLLOVAnf77_rvj_fg1PfluHF5_2-M0Og_z0yzBmaRZVz8ffbP8-Gff18f7Qw2t7FbtoluUTjhxXDDOJFN0sVQyHiKWNqODI9gB2nK1Wt7oRRe_OnHr2bvMmamvH0ws_Xb1IfB94LFvNvuDHVYJiN40HqewbedTWEOPGWcnkWbz1FsvGGosTSBgGDqTzY_3wjFRflp-0WXFlb5NGRbgrLphkksi03NzwaVGjWv-r4b5VvfUFqXJ2cG_myGBEZlGXJ-Iep4N7ooDz76OdhAjTrmOrISG5bXtzQGeA_0iqwHwmO-TefCoVuyZwJeKxQyddvQhM6LK4nJe3672ZZlDATstodzCRmscggTAP9hxKDjkHDYctjxBFgV1oVXEoxYMihwKK2BIhiKkd4purIRYrqgmiqFKTng0xXL_c8A7_EQVFNKYuwvFyXUx4CR3Cj4r2FPXMN2l4TkBZzXEqNxRvA16eDn5TvvZxJ2E9wW5OA1ehL4Fj8v9Cw)

Input is two lists of strings. Naive string operations.

- -6 bytes from @pajonk: alias `str.replace` to `r`
- -24 bytes from @Kevin Cruijssen: output a list instead of a string

Comment: [-6 bytes?](https://tio.run/##fVCxbtswEN31FQd2OLJiBITdDBhFDVdbFhdaKmlQYspioUgCxRYNgny7ezzaDtqhFEAd37337pHLSxjm6dPZPS@zD7C@rBq8zfptcx6758djByc9bBCw@DG7SZ7yQeV0yr2M3ztebzZ3920@pL/S1NECQahcoNDC8CYUYbESKvPbNfjC22Xsnuy5nz2M4KYYoFjD0U2bDORo@0Bx3GkICrYwUse7RapiXUYXpCCMnCDSqPS2WH8@Si9k/eXue1s3aNrPSpABiuZeaNTMVNehEnVLGLb47mF/dSOPVdkHWLybwj@nFCaDmci9/Jia0K2rpdcjcJviauhF2bnRHuE1ct50MwEt@3uxT4HQRrwy8a0RqcPrNIfYmQkV57ouoYJDq6Hew65taSIDQCc4IFQIJcIOYY8ZcQkwN7ZJ9IRFgWGFIQcqWVDF9sHwTk5EKw17EhhdSqYnUbL7nwL@ol9YFZcc83BjIatuAkryYOCrgW88Naa7Dbw24IrGmpAHrvcRjzdn3eV9dulN4v0iXF2CV3FuhX8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [83 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZBBb6MwEIXv/IqRexjTOEh1b5GiqlGWWy5ZcSn4QBMDrggg411tVfW3Z8d2kmr3UA4wfvO9eYOnd9eNw@PZnKbROpjfZwFWJ826Ovf16fVYQyu6VbvoFqXllp8WDJlgMrxYKhj6iqXNaOEEZoC2XK2WD2rRxa9K7Hp2NrN66uuDPnuu9xwFZbM7mmGVAO914yjWtJ1LYQ09dayZeJrNU28cZ6SxNAGPUWl1Nv965Zbx8nn5osoKpXpKGQ1AVj0wgSKQ6TWUo1CkocKvGfp33YfYNLmDyZrB/XeKyyQwEtzw@9iEep413RICZm@jGfhI667j4gIaltem10f48PSnqAagR/@Z9MGRWrGPAH5WLHbC047Od0ZS2bkscyhgrwSUW9goRdlBADrBHqFAyBE2CFtMiCVB3mgZ8ah5gwwOSROoDIbCt/cyvGkSYbkMM0n0U/KAR1Mc950D/sEvVBHKsOb@RmFw3Qy0yU7CDwk/Q6rf7hZ4bcBV9TUpu1Bvve7/PPgu97OJd@L/z8vFZfHC5xb4Fw) if you output as list as well.